# How to commit (not load!) an svn dump?

Tags: svn, svndump

I have my own SVN server. But I need to move a project from it to another one, which is not under my administration. I know you can load a dump and this is simple if you have access to it, but I don't. So...

**Is it possible to commit a dump (a number of revisions) to an SVN server?**

If so, how?

Comment: It doesn't help you right now, but this feature is coming in SVN 1.7: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#svnrdump

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only tool I can think of is [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html):

> svnsync is the Subversion remote repository mirroring tool. Put
>   simply, it allows you to replay the revisions of one repository into
>   another one.
>
> In any mirroring scenario, there are two repositories: the source
>   repository, and the mirror (or “sink”) repository. The source
>   repository is the repository from which svnsync pulls revisions. The
>   mirror repository is the destination for the revisions pulled from the
>   source repository. Each of the repositories may be local or
>   remote—they are only ever addressed by their URLs.
>
> The svnsync process requires only read access to the source
>   repository; it never attempts to modify it. But obviously, svnsync
>   requires both read and write access to the mirror repository.

Comment: Am I correct to think that it only allows for live sync? So only commits that are made with svnsync running are being synced with remote server?

Comment: Nope. It's not even a server or daemon. The only restriction I can see is that the target repo must be empty.

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro. Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I will accept your answer once I test it. Cheers!